# Finding the order of $a^7$ and $a^{10}$ given $\lvert a\rvert = 24$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G, *)$ be a group, with $a \in G$.  If $o(a) = 24,$ then find $o(a^7),\, o(a^{10}).$

Is the answer of both $24$?

Comment: **Hint** use the formula $$|a^k|=\dfrac{|a|}{Gcd(|k|,|a|)}$$

Comment: No, one of the answers is 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\gcd(24, 7) = 1.$ And $\gcd(24, 10) = 2$.

Note that we can express the order of a group element $g$ as $|g|$. I use that notation in what follows.

We can use the fact that $$|a^k| = \frac{|a|}{\gcd(|a|, |k|)}$$ to find the order of $a^7$ and $a^{10}$.

So, indeed, $|a^7| =|a| =24$, since $\gcd(24, 7) = 1$.

But the $\gcd(24, 10) = 2$, so that means $|a^{10}| = \dfrac{|a|}{\gcd(|a|, 10)} = \dfrac{24}{2} = 12.$